# Access a single R instance from multiple modules in package using rpy2

Tags: python, rpy2

How can one ensure only one R instance is run and accessible from modules in a package using rpy2?

For example, imagine the top level of a package `foobar` having modules foo.py and bar.py, as well as a subpackage "tests" with test module test_foo.py:

```
.
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test_foo.py
├── foo.py
├── bar.py
├── __init__.py
```

Can one place rpy2 imports in, say, the top level **init**.py, and then have all the other modules import `robjs`.  For example, the top level **init**.py can be:

```py
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as robjs
import rpy2.robjects.conversion as cv
from import rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
```

and then in the other modules:

```py
import foobar

# Do stuff with foobar.robjs, foobar.cv, foobar.pandas2ri
```

Or is there a better arrangement to have modules share the same R instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages/modules are singletons in Python (there is only one "copy" of each module across all imports within the same program).

You can `import rpy2.robjects as robjs` as many times and across as many modules as  you like, it will the very same R "instance" within a process.

To verify this you can add the following code snippet to all the modules you wrote for a program:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
rvar_name = 'import_%s' % __name__
ro.globalenv[rvar_name] = True
print('---')
print(__name__)
print(tuple(ro.globalenv.keys()))
print('---')
```

Comment: By R "instance" I mean the same R process, so that R objects are shared across modules importing `rpy2`, no matter where they are created.  Is that right?  Thanks!

Comment: R is embedded in a Python process (you start Python, and R is loaded into it when you import rpy2). I am adding a simple code example to demonstrate it.